# how to install C++14 on RHEL 7.4

Tags: c++, c++14, rhel7

My question is similar to [how to install gcc 4.9.2 on RHEL 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47175706/635160)

But I'm trying to get C++14 support on Red Hat 7 so I can install mapnik.

I've tried:
`# yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`

Install gcc, g++ version 4.9.2 : 
`# yum install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++`

Enabling gcc-4.9, g++-4.9 : `$ scl enable devtoolset-3 bash`

But I keep getting

> C++ compiler does not support C++14 standard (-std=c++14), which is required. Please upgrade your compiler

Comment: Simply install from sources. configure, make, make install...

Comment: You keep getting that message when? Are you specifically running the installed `g++`? Or are you just running your distro's default? Anyway, see the documentation on which versions of `g++` support which parts of which standards: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html Version 4.9 is not necessarily sufficient for your needs, as its C++14 implementation is incomplete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that devtoolset-3 contains the c++11 standard. Making and installing GCC from source caused two GCC versions to exist together. The default being the c++11 version. In order to get the correct version of gcc I needed to install devtoolset-7 and make sure devtoolset-3 was superseded or removed.

Here is how I enabled it:

### 1. Install a package with repository for your system:

#### On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for your system:

$ `sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`

#### 2. Install the collection:

$ `sudo yum install devtoolset-7`

#### 3. Start using software collections:

$ `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash`

Answer (score 0):

You can download GCC sources and build it.

Generally the process involve:

1. Download tar.gz with GCC source code, from here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/
2. Configure, Make and install. You can look for documentation in their site on how to do it, specifically you can start here:
   https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC