# Installing Network Simulator 2 on manjaro system

Tags: ns2

I tried to install ns2 on 4.9.68-1-MANJARO but got this error

```
    mdart/mdart_adp.cc:396:21: error: reference to ‘hash’ is ambiguous
  nsaddr_t dstAdd_ = hash(mdart_->id_);
                     ^~~~
In file included from ./mdart/mdart.h:52:0,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
                 from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
./mdart/mdart_function.h:230:17: note: candidates are: nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t)
 inline nsaddr_t hash(nsaddr_t id) {
                 ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:6575:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.1/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.2.1/bitset:47,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_function.h:62,
                 from ./mdart/mdart.h:52,
                 from ./mdart/mdart_adp.h:51,
                 from mdart/mdart_adp.cc:47:
/usr/include/c++/7.2.1/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12: note:                 template<class _Tp> struct std::hash
     struct hash;
            ^~~~
make: *** [Makefile:94: mdart/mdart_adp.o] Error 1
Ns make failed!
```

I changed line 137 from

```
void eraseAll() {erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
```

to

```
void eraseAll() { baseMap::erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }
```

but, still got the same error. Please help me.

Comment: `c++/7.2.1` : c++ / g++ version 7.2.1 . NS-2.35 can be compiled with g++ version 5.x (or 4.6.x ... 4.9.x) if the updated `ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz` is used. Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried it with gcc-4.9.3 to the one provided in the link, i changed the line 7 of otcl-1.14/Makefile.in to CC=     gcc-4.9.3. Still got the same error. Can you please tell me how to change from 7.2.1 to 4.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed the line 7 of otcl-1.14/Makefile.in to CC= gcc-4.9.3

The most important gcc component here is **g++**.

Building ns-2.35 with gcc-4.9.3 / g++-4.9.3 :

```
$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz
$ cd ns-allinone-2.35/
$ export CC=gcc-4.9.3 CXX=g++-4.9.3 && ./install
$ cd ns-2.35/
# make install
                  // 'make install' will copy 'ns' to /usr/local/bin/
# cd ../nam-1.15/
# make install && exit
```

Note : The (temporary) export command will take care that the main applications in ns-allinone are compiled with gcc-4.9.3 / g++-4.9.3 : tcl, tk, otcl, tclcl, **ns-2.35**, nam-1.15 . When exiting the terminal, the export command is cancelled.

---

EDIT Aug 31, 2020 : gcc49-bin-4.9.3-el6.tar.xz is available https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w0jT6q59rfZ-Bl--G5Y6jRVjjxu4CH68/view?usp=sharing

```
cd /usr/local/
# tar xvf gcc49-bin-4.9.3-el6.tar.xz
# cd bin/
# ln -s ../gcc493/bin/gcc49
# ln -s ../gcc493/bin/g++49
```

Comment: I've downloaded your archive from Google Drive, followed your script but still, I have the same problem with the OP, the hash function is ambiguous. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @NickDelta : The build command is `export CC=gcc-4.9.3 CXX=g++-4.9.3 && ./install` , i.e. one line in the terminal. .... Are you quite sure you did that ? I.e. i.e the export command is temporary. Will reset to the default /usr/bin/g++ , when exit the terminal.

Comment: Problem is probably that I have gcc 7.5.0 installed. How can I download and install 4.9.3 ?

Comment: Seems the arch/manjaro package gcc49 is no more ? .... Maybe you can extract the rpm package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 ... though the Arch rpm-tools / rpmextract also seems unavailable. .... Else : I can upload a tar.xz version.

Answer (score 0):

*We have to edit source code of ns-allinone-2.35 . It contains some errors there :*

**In `ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/mdart/` we have to edit `3` files**

- 1st file is `mdart_function.h` , At line number `230` rename `hash` to `hash_`
- 2nd file is `mdart_adp.cc` , at line number `108` and `396` rename `hash` to `hash_` .

> Reason why we need to change `hash` to `hash_` is.! , `hash` is `STL library utility` , so it will directly refers to `STL std::hash` . so that I renamed `hash` to `hash_`

- 3rd file is `mdart_function.h` , at line number `48` rewrite line like this `#define __mdart_rqueue_h__` .

> Reason is , If we are writing header file then 1st we have to write like,

```
#ifdefn __filename_h__
#define __filename_h__
```

> in `filename.h` only .

**Now In `ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/linkstate/` we have to edit `ls.h` file**

- At line number `64` rewrite like `#ifndef __ls_h__` and `65` should be like `#define __ls_h__`

That's all. After this go head to install .

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there is a package in the package manager named "ns".
It is of the same version, i.e. 2.35-9 available in the AUR. It got installed without any hassle and flaw for me.

Do give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this, worked for EndeavourOS

https://github.com/rakin000/ns2installation-archlinux

## Install ns-2.35 and nam-1.15 on ArchLinux(EndeavourOS)

### Install gcc-4.8

- If you don't have 'yay', install it.

  - Clone [yay](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/yay)

  ```bash
     git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
  ```

  - Change directory and install

  ```bash
     cd yay
     makepkg -si
  ```
- Now install gcc-4.8

  ```bash
     yay -S gcc48
  ```

### Download [ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11rYcVLmZw8aF_F0-3uealuScGoO1tWMo/view?usp=sharing)

- Extract and change directory

  ```bash
    tar -xf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz 
    cd ns-allinone-2.35/
  ```

### Install nam-1.15 and ns-2.35

- First install dependencies

```bash
   sudo pacman -S libx11 libxmu
```

- To install, run

```bash
    export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./install
```

- After this script runs successfully

  - Change directory to nam-1.15 and install

  ```bash
     cd nam-1.15/
     sudo make install
  ```

  - Change directory to ns-2.35 and install

  ```bash
      cd ../ns-2.35/
      sudo make install
  ```