# Unable to build vowpal wabbit in centos 7

Tags: python, build, centos7, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to install vowpal wabbit in a virtual env in centos 7. I have installed the dependencies like boost(https://medium.com/@royendgel/boost-boost-python-dlib-python3-on-centos-or-amazon-linux-4039f70a3614) required.

Python : 3.6
Cmake : 3.6.2 (Installed as per this doc : http://jotmynotes.blogspot.com/2016/10/updating-cmake-from-2811-to-362-or.html)

Here is the error when running "make install". I followed the instruction for Linux from https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Installing.

```
 Scanning dependencies of target spanning_tree
[  1%] Building CXX object cluster/CMakeFiles/spanning_tree.dir/spanning_tree_main.cc.o
[  1%] Building CXX object cluster/CMakeFiles/spanning_tree.dir/__/vowpalwabbit/spanning_tree.cc.o
[  2%] Building CXX object cluster/CMakeFiles/spanning_tree.dir/__/vowpalwabbit/vw_exception.cc.o
[  3%] Linking CXX executable spanning_tree
[  3%] Built target spanning_tree
[  6%] Built target allreduce
[  6%] Building CXX object vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/audit_regressor.cc.o
In file included from /home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/reductions.h:9:0,
                 from /home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/audit_regressor.cc:5:
/home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/global_data.h:479:30: warning: missing initializer for member ‘std::array<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, std::unique_ptr<features> > > >, 256ul>::_M_elems’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
       namespace_dictionaries{};  // each namespace has a list of dictionaries attached to it
                              ^
In file included from /home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/global_data.h:49:0,
                 from /home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/reductions.h:9,
                 from /home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/audit_regressor.cc:5:
/home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/options.h: In instantiation of ‘VW::config::typed_option<T>::typed_option(const string&, T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
/home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/options.h:97:40:   required from ‘VW::config::typed_option<T> VW::config::make_option(std::string, T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
/home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/audit_regressor.cc:249:58:   required from here
/home/joel/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/options.h:37:117: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::basic_string<char>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
   typed_option(const std::string& name, T& location) : base_option(name, typeid(T).hash_code()), m_location{location} {}
                                                                                                                     ^
make[2]: *** [vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/audit_regressor.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [vowpalwabbit/CMakeFiles/vw.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to the `vowpal_wabbit` version used. ... Latest is https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit ... **Important** : A c++11 compiler, e.g. `g++-7.3`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 ... And probably a boost version built with c++11.

Answer (score 2):

> trying to install vowpal wabbit

The g++ compiler must be a c++11 version. Boost must be compiled with  c++11 ... see [how to install gcc 4.9.2 on RHEL 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915)

**CentOS 7** : Build example, in /home/[name]/tmp/

```
======= Boost ========
cd boost_1_68_0/
echo "using gcc : : /usr/bin/g++73 ; " >> tools/build/src/user-config.jam
echo "using python : 3.6 : /usr/bin/python3.6 : /usr/include/python3.6m ; " >> tools/build/src/user-config.jam

./bootstrap.sh
./b2
# ./b2 install

======== dlib ============
cd dlib-19.19.0/ && python3 setup.py build
# python3 setup.py install

======== VowpalWabbit ========
git clone https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit.git
cd vowpal_wabbit/
git submodule update --init --recursive
mkdir build && cd build/
CC=gcc73 CXX=g++73 cmake3 ..
make      // no errors
```

P.S.: Ref. README.md → the new "Building information" is here https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Building → **Warning** : Doing 'make' in vowpal_wabbit/ can configure for Python 2 only.

---

Building the **python3** bindings for VowpalWabbit : As the default Makefile and the cmake options are for python2 only, this is the solution:

```
cd vowpal_wabbit/
export CC=gcc73 CXX=g++73 && python3 setup.py build
.
[100%] Built target pylibvw
.
# export CC=gcc73 CXX=g++73 && python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear linux centos 7

- yum update
- instal gcc*
- install cmake-3.10.2.tar.gz
- install boost_1_65_1.tar.gz
- install java-1.8

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/boost/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

BOOST_ROOT=/opt/boost(choose location in install)
export BOOST_ROOT
...
cd build; cmake ..

Complete.