# How to remove gcc 7.3 from RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, gcc, rhel7

RHEL 7 comes with built-in gcc of version 4.8. 
If I do

**yum remove gcc**

then it removes gcc 4.8. How can I remove gcc 7.3 from the system completely?
I have tried to find the solution for the above problem but most of the solution is for Ubuntu. Can someone help to figure out a solution for CentOS/RHEL?
Thanks.

Note:

> which gcc

```
/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

> gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give version number in package name to yum:

```
yum remove gcc-7.3.0
```

Comment: A manually installed gcc in  /usr/local/ : Delete all files related to the alien gcc. ... I.e. you can have one `gcc` only in the PATH. ... Note : Extra compilers must be build so none of their files can disturb the system gcc files. Like these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915