# How to install a newer version of libstdc++ on Centos 7

Tags: c++, centos, centos7, libstdc++

I am running an application and it throws me an error saying:

"C++ header 'string_view' is required.  You need to install a newer libstdc++ on the host system."

Can someone guide me on what I need to do to get a newer version of "libstdc++" on my machine?

Thanks

Comment: g++ version 7.x has like `gcc73/include/c++/7.3.0/string_view`. ... Earlier modern  g++ versions (5.x ... 6 ) have the header `string_view` located in "experimental/" . .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Answer (score 2):

Try running `yum provides libstdc++` to show you what package provided the library on your system. You can then check if those packages are available for update using `yum list available | grep <that package>` followed by `yum update <that package>`.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, I built gcc from source. This way you get to choose your own version. It's actually pretty straightforard -- see *Building GCC* at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC.