# Building Glibc 2.33 for Linux results in unit test failures

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, vmware, glibc

I'm currently trying to create a build of **Glibc 2.33** to live in parallel to the default system version, but the build process is resulting in a large number of unit test failures. While some of the failures might be safe to ignore, most seem like legitimate problems, but I'm not sure how to fix them. The desired final target system is **CentOS 7.9**, but I'm currently testing the build steps in **Ubuntu Desktop 21.04** (in a **VMware 15** VM) since **CentOS 7.9** requires creating a bootstrap tool-chain (the default tool-chain is too old). According to the **Glibc 2.33** documentation, the `--enable-add-ons` option is no longer required (and might even be unsupported), so I'm not sure what steps or configuration options I could be missing.

## The steps followed to create the build VM

1. Create a "clean", minimal **Ubuntu Desktop 21.04** VM installation
2. Fully update the VM
3. Install the following packages

- `build-essential`
- `gawk`
- `bison`
- `texinfo`
- `msgfmt`
- `gettext`

### Software versions of the resultant system

- **GCC**: Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1
- **Binutils**: 2.36.1
- **Make**: 4.3
- **Bison**: 3.7.5
- **Gawk**: 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
- **Python 3**: 3.9.5
- **PExpect**: 4.8.0
- **Perl**: 5.32.1
- **Texinfo**: 6.7.0
- **Sed**: 4.7
- **Gdb**: Ubuntu 10.1-2ubuntu2 (10.1.90.20210411-git)

## Glibc 2.33 build steps:

1. Download the **Glibc 2.33** source code

   ```
    wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.33.tar.gz -P ${HOME}/Downloads
   ```
2. Create directories

   ```
    rm -rf ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain && mkdir -p ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Build
   ```
3. Extract the **Glibc 2.33** source code

   ```
    tar -xf ${HOME}/Downloads/glibc-2.33.tar.gz -C ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain
   ```
4. Enter the (out-of-source) build directory

   ```
    cd ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Build
   ```
5. Configure **Glibc 2.33**

   ```
    ../glibc-2.33/configure --prefix=${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install 2>&1 | tee output-configure.txt
   ```
6. Build **Glibc 2.33**

   ```
    make -j`nproc` 2>&1 | tee output-make.txt
   ```
7. Build and run the unit tests

   ```
    make check 2>&1 | tee output-make-check.txt
   ```

## Unit test results

The above steps result in the following unit test results, including 149 failed tests.

```
FAIL: debug/tst-backtrace2
FAIL: debug/tst-backtrace3
FAIL: debug/tst-backtrace4
FAIL: debug/tst-backtrace5
FAIL: debug/tst-backtrace6
FAIL: dlfcn/bug-atexit3
FAIL: elf/check-abi-libc
UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-audit10
UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-avx512
UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-legacy-8
UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-property-2
FAIL: elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo
FAIL: elf/tst-glibc-hwcaps-prepend-cache
FAIL: elf/tst-ldconfig-ld_so_conf-update
XPASS: elf/tst-protected1a
XPASS: elf/tst-protected1b
FAIL: elf/tst-unwind-main
FAIL: iconv/tst-iconv-mt
FAIL: malloc/tst-malloc-stats-cancellation
FAIL: malloc/tst-malloc-stats-cancellation-mcheck
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-sincos-avx512
UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-sincosf-avx512
FAIL: misc/tst-gettid-kill
UNSUPPORTED: misc/tst-pkey
FAIL: misc/tst-sigcontext-get_pc
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-cond-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-condattr-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutex-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutexattr-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlock-printers
UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlockattr-printers
FAIL: nptl/tst-basic3
FAIL: nptl/tst-basic4
FAIL: nptl/tst-call-once
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel-self
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel-self-cancelstate
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel-self-canceltype
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel-self-testcancel
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel1
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel10
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel11
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel12
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel13
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel14
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel15
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel16
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel17
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel18
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel2
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel20
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel21
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel22
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel23
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel24
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel25
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel28
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel3
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel4
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel4_1
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel4_2
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel5
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel6
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel7
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel8
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancel9
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx10
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx11
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx12
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx13
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx14
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx15
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx16
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx17
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx18
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx2
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx20
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx21
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx3
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx4
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx5
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx6
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx7
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx8
FAIL: nptl/tst-cancelx9
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanup0
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanup0-cmp
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanup1
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanup3
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanup4
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanupx0
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanupx1
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanupx3
FAIL: nptl/tst-cleanupx4
FAIL: nptl/tst-cnd-basic
FAIL: nptl/tst-cnd-broadcast
FAIL: nptl/tst-cnd-timedwait
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond-except
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond22
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond25
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond7
FAIL: nptl/tst-cond8
FAIL: nptl/tst-default-attr
FAIL: nptl/tst-exec5
FAIL: nptl/tst-execstack
FAIL: nptl/tst-exit2
FAIL: nptl/tst-exit3
FAIL: nptl/tst-fini1
FAIL: nptl/tst-join1
FAIL: nptl/tst-join10
FAIL: nptl/tst-join11
FAIL: nptl/tst-join12
FAIL: nptl/tst-join13
FAIL: nptl/tst-join5
FAIL: nptl/tst-join6
FAIL: nptl/tst-join8
FAIL: nptl/tst-join9
FAIL: nptl/tst-key3
FAIL: nptl/tst-minstack-cancel
FAIL: nptl/tst-minstack-exit
FAIL: nptl/tst-minstack-throw
FAIL: nptl/tst-mtx-basic
FAIL: nptl/tst-mtx-timedlock
FAIL: nptl/tst-mtx-trylock
FAIL: nptl/tst-mutex10
FAIL: nptl/tst-mutex8
FAIL: nptl/tst-mutexpi8
FAIL: nptl/tst-once3
FAIL: nptl/tst-once4
FAIL: nptl/tst-oncex3
FAIL: nptl/tst-oncex4
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust1
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust2
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust3
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust4
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust5
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust6
FAIL: nptl/tst-robust7
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi1
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi2
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi3
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi4
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi5
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi6
FAIL: nptl/tst-robustpi7
FAIL: nptl/tst-sem11
FAIL: nptl/tst-sem12
FAIL: nptl/tst-sem16
FAIL: nptl/tst-stack4
FAIL: nptl/tst-thrd-detach
FAIL: nptl/tst-thrd-sleep
FAIL: nptl/tst-thread-exit-clobber
FAIL: nptl/tst-thread_local1
FAIL: nptl/tst-tsd5
FAIL: nptl/tst-tss-basic
FAIL: nptl/tst-unwind-thread
FAIL: nss/tst-cancel-getpwuid_r
FAIL: nss/tst-nss-files-hosts-long
UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-cet-vfork-1
FAIL: posix/tst-getopt-cancel
UNSUPPORTED: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn
UNSUPPORTED: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn-latin1
FAIL: rt/tst-cpuclock2
FAIL: rt/tst-mqueue8
FAIL: rt/tst-mqueue8x
FAIL: rt/tst-shm-cancel
FAIL: stdlib/tst-quick_exit
FAIL: stdlib/tst-thread-quick_exit
Summary of test results:
    149 FAIL
   4202 PASS
     16 UNSUPPORTED
     17 XFAIL
      2 XPASS
```

### Select detailed failed test results

- **tst-backtrace2**

  ```
    Obtained backtrace with 0 functions
    Failure on line 44
  ```
- **tst-backtrace3**

  ```
    Obtained backtrace with 0 functions
    Failure on line 49
  ```
- **dlfcn/bug-atexit3**

  ```
    dlopen failed: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```
- **elf/check-abi-libc**

  ```
    --- ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/libc.abilist   2021-02-01 12:15:33.000000000 -0500
    +++ /home/sandy/Projects/BuildToolchain/Build/libc.symlist      2021-07-12 11:42:58.693499635 -0400
    @@ -499 +499 @@ GLIBC_2.2.5 _mcount F
    -GLIBC_2.2.5 _nl_default_dirname D 0x12
    +GLIBC_2.2.5 _nl_default_dirname D 0x39
  ```
- **misc/tst-gettid-kill**

  ```
    Didn't expect signal from child: got `Aborted'
  ```
- **nptl/tst-basic3**

  ```
    starting 20 + 1 threads
    20 left
    Incorrect signal from child: got `Aborted', need `User defined signal 1'
  ```
- **nss/tst-nss-files-hosts-long** (This test passes if the `--prefix` commandline option is not used)

  ```
    error: tst-nss-files-hosts-long.c:35: ahostsv4 failed
    error: 1 test failures
  ```
- **posix/tst-getopt-cancel**

  ```
    begin: no errors
    Didn't expect signal from child: got `Aborted'
  ```
- **rt/tst-cpuclock2**

  ```
    live thread clock ffffffffff031f26 resolution 0.000000001
    live thread before sleep => 0.000115540
    self thread before sleep => 0.000294453
    live thread after sleep => 0.500264022
    self thread after sleep => 0.000336234
    Didn't expect signal from child: got `Aborted'
  ```
- **stdlib/tst-quick_exit**

  ```
     (empty)
  ```
- **stdlib/tst-thread-quick_exit**

  ```
    (empty)
  ```

Comment: Probably start from scratch: `make clean && make -j1` https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/glibc.html ..... Expected `make check` failures https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter08/glibc.html ....... Extra compilers for EL7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Comment: It's not immediately clear why all the tests fail. You should look at (and update the question with) the contents of `dlfcn/bug-atexit3.out`, etc.

Comment: Absence of `libstdc++.so.6` may indicate that your install is *too* minimal. At any rate, https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/ could be a more appropriate forum for this.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., A "minimal" Ubuntu Desktop installation just results in some productivity software and games not getting installed. However, all of the expected GNU/Linux packages are installed in addition to Gnome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: **Glibc-2.33** : CentOS7 example , {make-4.2.1-10.el7, gcc84} → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/102smch2OEpqybmMMUntyCfmuPpXDzLFT?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen, Thank you for the example. Do you know if the 138 failures in your example are safe and expected?

Comment: No. Build reports / make check reports : There may be some in "Linux From Scratch Forums". ..... Expected make check failures: Please see my first comment.

Comment: @KnudLarsen, thank you for the response. I've already looked through the LFS book many times, but I'm not finding it very helpful for this particular issue. Its list of expected failures doesn't mention many of the failures that I've been seeing (both in Ubuntu and CentOS) and are in your example as well (e.g., tst-backtrace*). Additionally, the expected failure lists that I've been able to find are not very specific as to under what conditions the tests are expected to fail. This build will be used in a regulated space, so all failures must be understood before the build can be used.

Comment: A perfect build would be "follow the book" e.g. LFS-10.1, where a clean binutils etc. is used. I.e. a sequence with no Ubuntu or CentOS binutils etc. in the final result. I vote for a build with CentOS7, not Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reported failures all seem to be related to bugs and limitations in the **Glibc 2.33** test harness, plus one VM-related bug.

## Detailed test failure explanations

**elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo** 
This test is failing due to a VM software bug and not because of **Glibc 2.33**. The error log is shown below and can be ignored when the build is performed in a VM (although the build should probably be performed on a host to minimize any chance of optimizations getting disabled).

```
    [snip]
    Checking HAS_CPU_FEATURE (ERMS):
      HAS_CPU_FEATURE (ERMS): 1
      cpuinfo (erms): 0
     *** failure ***
    [snip]
    1 differences between /proc/cpuinfo and glibc code.
```

See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26823, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1128638
and https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24080

**nptl/tst-mutex10** 
This test is timing out.

**Remaining 147 tests** 
These tests are failing due to a limitation in the test harness related "to when a build is configured for a non-standard prefix (i.e. not `/usr`)" (see the **bug-atexit3 and nptl tests** section of https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Testsuite)

## Workaround

**** Please note: The following directions should probably not be directly followed to create a new "stand-alone" build of **Glibc 2.33**. Instead, these directions should be incorporated into a larger set of steps that build an entire toolchain (**GCC**, **Binutils**, **Glibc**, etc.) ****

The following workaround can be used to build **Glibc 2.33** in **Ubuntu 21.04** with the default compiler. Optionally first, build **Glibc 2.33** by setting the prefix to `/usr` and verify only the **elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo** test fails (the test should only fail when built in a VM). Then, rebuild **Glibc 2.33** with the desired prefix.

### Build **Glibc 2.33** with prefix set to `/usr`

**** WARNING: DO NOT PERFORM A `make install` OR THE SYSTEM WILL BE CORRUPTED ****

The following build steps will result in a build with only a single failure (**elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo**) when performed on a VM and should result in no failures when performed directly on a host computer (configured as described in the question).

```
    wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.33.tar.gz -P ${HOME}/Downloads
    rm -rf ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchainUsr && mkdir -p ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchainUsr/Build
    tar -xf ${HOME}/Downloads/glibc-2.33.tar.gz -C ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchainUsr
    cd ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchainUsr/Build
    ../glibc-2.33/configure --prefix=/usr 2>&1 | tee output-configure.txt
    make -j`nproc` 2>&1 | tee output-make.txt
    make check 2>&1 | tee output-make-check.txt
```

The above steps should result the following test results:

```
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-audit10
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-legacy-8
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-property-2
    FAIL: elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo
    XPASS: elf/tst-protected1a
    XPASS: elf/tst-protected1b
    UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-sincos-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-sincosf-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: misc/tst-pkey
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-cond-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-condattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutex-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutexattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlock-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlockattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-cet-vfork-1
    Summary of test results:
          1 FAIL
       4352 PASS
         14 UNSUPPORTED
         17 XFAIL
          2 XPASS
```

## Build **Glibc 2.33** with the desired prefix

**Glibc 2.33** can then be built with the following commands to use the desired prefix value. While 2 tests will fail (1 if built directly on a host), the failures are a result of the test harness's limitations and can be safely ignored.

### Detailed workaround explanation

The workaround resolves all but one of the prefix related test failures by creating symlinks for `libstdc++.so.6` and `libgcc_s.so.1` plus executing the test suite twice, creating additional symlinks before the second execution. The first two symlinks ensure all unit tests are able to find both `libstdc++.so.6` and `libgcc_s.so.1`. When the test suite is first run, a directory named `testroot.pristine` is created, which is used to provide a clean **chroot** for each unit test. At the start of an individual unit test, the `testroot.pristine` directory is copied to `testroot.root` (replacing any existing `testroot.root` directories) and a **chroot** is setup. Individual unit test can have test specific files that get copied into the `testroot.root` directory.

After the first execution of the test suite, there will be 5 failures (4 if run outside of a VM). Three of these failures are due to the unit tests assuming the prefix is always `/usr`. To resolve this, a second set of symlinks are created in the `testroot.prestine` directory, to ensure the 3 unit tests are able to find the required files. All of the `*.out` files in the `Build` directory are then deleted so the full test suite can be rerun without recreating the `testroot.prestine` directory.

```
    rm -rf ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain && mkdir -p ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Build
    tar -xf ${HOME}/Downloads/glibc-2.33.tar.gz -C ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain
    cd ${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Build
    ../glibc-2.33/configure --prefix=${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install 2>&1 | tee output-configure.txt
    make -j`nproc` 2>&1 | tee output-make.txt
    ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    TIMEOUTFACTOR=16 make check 2>&1 | tee output-make-checkA.txt
    mkdir testroot.pristine/usr
    ln -s ${HOME#/}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/etc testroot.pristine/etc
    ln -s ${HOME#/}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/lib testroot.pristine/lib64
    ln -s ${HOME#/}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/sbin testroot.pristine/sbin
    ln -s ${HOME#/}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/var testroot.pristine/var
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/bin testroot.pristine/usr/bin
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/include testroot.pristine/usr/include
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/lib testroot.pristine/usr/lib
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/lib testroot.pristine/usr/lib64
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/libexec testroot.pristine/usr/libexec
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/sbin testroot.pristine/usr/sbin
    ln -s ..${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/share testroot.pristine/usr/share
    find -name "*.out" -delete
    TIMEOUTFACTOR=16 make check 2>&1 | tee output-make-checkB.txt
```

### Notes

**TIMEOUTFACTOR**: This environment variable is used to increase the timeout value used by the test harness.

The expected test output after the first `make check` command:

```
    FAIL: elf/check-abi-libc
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-audit10
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-legacy-8
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-property-2
    FAIL: elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo
    FAIL: elf/tst-glibc-hwcaps-prepend-cache
    FAIL: elf/tst-ldconfig-ld_so_conf-update
    XPASS: elf/tst-protected1a
    XPASS: elf/tst-protected1b
    UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-sincos-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-sincosf-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: misc/tst-pkey
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-cond-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-condattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutex-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutexattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlock-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlockattr-printers
    FAIL: nss/tst-nss-files-hosts-long
    UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-cet-vfork-1
    UNSUPPORTED: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn
    UNSUPPORTED: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn-latin1
    Summary of test results:
          5 FAIL
       4346 PASS
         16 UNSUPPORTED
         17 XFAIL
          2 XPASS
```

The expected test output after the second `make check` command:

```
    FAIL: elf/check-abi-libc
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-audit10
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-legacy-8
    UNSUPPORTED: elf/tst-cet-property-2
    FAIL: elf/tst-cpu-features-cpuinfo
    XPASS: elf/tst-protected1a
    XPASS: elf/tst-protected1b
    UNSUPPORTED: math/test-double-libmvec-sincos-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: math/test-float-libmvec-sincosf-avx512
    UNSUPPORTED: misc/tst-pkey
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-cond-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-condattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutex-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-mutexattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlock-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: nptl/test-rwlockattr-printers
    UNSUPPORTED: posix/tst-cet-vfork-1
    UNSUPPORTED: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn
    UNSUPPORTED: resolv/tst-resolv-ai_idn-latin1
    Summary of test results:
          2 FAIL
       4349 PASS
         16 UNSUPPORTED
         17 XFAIL
          2 XPASS
```

### Detailed test failure explanations

**elf/check-abi-libc**
This test fails because the `_nl_default_dirname` symbol stores the path to the `locale` file (see https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2012-December/036816.html). When the prefix is set to `/usr`, the `locale` file path is `/usr/share/locale` but with the above directions, the path is `${HOME}/Projects/BuildToolchain/Install/share/locale` (with the `${HOME}` variable expanded). This failure can safely be ignored.

```
    --- ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/libc.abilist   2021-02-01 12:15:33.000000000 -0500
    +++ /home/sandy/Projects/BuildToolchain/Build/libc.symlist      2021-07-14 18:18:50.040682543 -0400
    @@ -499 +499 @@ GLIBC_2.2.5 _mcount F
    -GLIBC_2.2.5 _nl_default_dirname D 0x12
    +GLIBC_2.2.5 _nl_default_dirname D 0x39
```