# Updating /usr/include/c++ in CentOS-7

Tags: centos7, libstdc++, devtoolset

I have installed the `devtoolset-10` package on CentOS 7 and run the `/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/enable` script so that now when I do this:

```sh
g++ --version
```

I get this:

```sh
g++ (GCC) 10.2.1 20210130 (Red Hat 10.2.1-11)
```

Great. Trouble is, the headers under `/usr/include/c++` still point to ye olde `libstdc++-4.8.5`. That is, if I do `ls` in `/usr/include/c++`, all I see is:

```sh
bash-4.2$ ls /usr/include/c++
4.8.2  4.8.5
```

What is the magic incantation to "enable" `libstdc++-10` to be the default system C++ stdlib?

Answer (score 3):

> devtoolset-10

Every g++ comes with it's own headers. `/usr/include/c++/4.8*` is for 4.8.5 only.

devtoolset-10: g++ version 10 is using the headers at `/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10`

> "enable" libstdc++-10

There is no shared library "libstdc++-10". There is `/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/{ libstdc++.a, libstdc++.so }` , where libstdc++.so is a ~200B text file.

Comment: So if you want to to tell e.g. cmake to reference headers in c++/10 as opposed to c++/4.8, export `CXX` env var [per below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73558575/1080804)

Comment: @ecoe → Selecting header version. That's easy, just set the preferred 'g++' for cmake, with e.g.  `$ CC=g++73 CXX=g++73 cmake ..` ... and the "version 7.3" headers will be used. ... Ref. extra gcc/g++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Answer (score 1):

I guess the users are supposed to query gcc for the include path.
On my CentOS /usr/include/c++ is not a symlink, and is not supposed to point anywhere, but one can work around that using update-alternatives (I did that only for the compiler itself only, though). Might be overriden by an update, but those don't happen often enough on CentOS.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer as opposed to a useful comment.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the magic incantation to "enable" `libstdc++-10` to be the default system C++ stdlib?

Developer Toolset uses a hybrid linkage model. This means that it does not come with its own `libstdc++.so.6`, but uses the system version as far as possible. The missing parts are linked statically. This is achieved by the linker script that [Knud Larsen mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69100907/8316315).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile using headers from the latest C++ compiler you have on Centos7:

1. Remove your build directory
2. **Export your chosen compiler** specifically: `export CXX=g++`

Thanks to this comment from [github](https://github.com/gunrock/gunrock/issues/704#issuecomment-594136145):