# Unable to compile GCC any version of my CentOS system

Tags: gcc, pthreads

I tried to install different version of GCC instead of 'devtoolset-*'. But My model keeps failing me with a messages saying '!$OMP& PRIVATE(ierr, thread_id, core_id, hex_char, isubstr) internal compiler error: in gimplify_expr, at gimplify.c:11859'

So started installing other version of GCC downloaded at 'https://ftp.gnu.org/' but It keeps failing and saying this bunch of error messagges

**checking what to include in gstdint.h... stdint.h (already complete)**

**configure: error: Pthreads are required to build libgomp**

**make[2]: [configure-stage1-target-libgomp] error 1**

**make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/CESM_ref/CESM_porting/script/gcc-7.3.0'**

**make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] error 2**

**make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/CESM_ref/CESM_porting/script/gcc-7.3.0'**

**make: [all] error 2**

**make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/CESM_ref/CESM_porting/script/gcc-7.3.0'**

**make[2]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/CESM_ref/CESM_porting/script/gcc-7.3.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes'**

**make[2]:  타겟 `install'를 만들 규칙이 없음.  멈춤.**

**make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/CESM_ref/CESM_porting/script/gcc-7.3.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/fixincludes'**

**make[1]: *** [install-fixincludes] 오류 2**

**make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/CESM_ref/CESM_porting/script/gcc-7.3.0'**

**make: *** [install] 오류 2****

This is the command line I used.

**./configure --prefix=/home/vagrant/modules/gcc-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib**

Thanks you for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: gcc-7.3.0 see item 7, etc. etc. gcc rpm packages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 ..... Build gcc 7.3.0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cdifwDim3M0CfkJsH6C_HatyhM_M3AOg/view?usp=sharing ........ Important: gcc requires a build/ folder outside the gcc source directory.