# Enabling libasan (address sanitizer, dynamically linked) with gcc on AWS Linux 2

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, sanitization, address-sanitizer

I have a project for which I would like to enable the address sanitizer during testing. It is being built and tested on AWS Linux 2 and the compiler is gcc 7.3.1. I need to have libasan dynamically linked because I am testing a Python extension module and the Python executable itself is not built with asan.

After building/ linking my code with `-fsanitize=address`, I am starting python (which will load my code) with `LD_PRELOAD` as `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/libasan.so`. That is the path I get from `gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so` (and I have confirmed it exists).

When I run, I get

`ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/libasan.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (file too short): ignored.`

Why is this? How do I get libasan to be used? Do I need to install an additional package?

Comment: Please try `cat  libasan.so` : Can be a 82B text file. A real "shared libasan.so" is a symlink to the ~1.3MB libasan.so.4.0.0 . Example EL7, see item #7  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915