# GCC gcc-5.4.0 build on centos7

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

On centos 7 i am trying to install GCC 5.4 via source code but it went into infinite loop always.

Environment :-

```
uname -a
Linux  3.10.0-1062.12.1.rt56.1042.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Feb 5 10:31:05 CET 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

rpm -qa | grep -i gcc
libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
gcc-c++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
gcc-gfortran-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
gcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Now, I tried to build GCC 5.4 and getting below message on my screen in infinite loop.

My config.log initial content as below.

```
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.10.0-1062.12.1.rt56.1042.el7.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Feb 5 10:31:05 CET 2020

/usr/bin/uname -p = x86_64
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown
```

```
# make -j$(nproc) && make install
checking for compatible ISL... no
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     target-libmpx gnattools gotools target-libada target-libgfortran target-libgo target-libffi target-libbacktrace target-zlib target-libjava target-libobjc target-liboffloadmic target-boehm-gc
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... bootstrap-debug
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... makeinfo
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-as... no
checking for as... as
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ld... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-lipo... no
checking for lipo... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-nm... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-windmc... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-objcopy... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for x86_64-linux-gnu-readelf... no
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcj... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for gccgo... no
checking for ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... no
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objcopy... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... no
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... just compiled
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... just compiled
checking where to find the target gcj... host tool
checking where to find the target gfortran... host tool
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objcopy... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
```

Any suggestion to install GCC will help a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to install (or build) prehistoric version of GCC?

Comment: Make it easy. Install docker and run `docker run gcc:5.4`. (argh, you will need to update kernel)

Comment: you might find [dev toolset](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/user/rhscl/?search=Developer&policy=&repo=&order_by=-create_date&per_page=10) an easier way to install a newer version of gcc (though it doesn't support GCC 5)

Comment: What message? 4.8 to 5.4 is not a large leap. The main thing is to ensure you are doing an out-of-source build, and downloaded the prerequisites using the provided script.

Comment: Extra gcc/g++, EL6 and EL7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 ....... Build gcc v5.4 https://drive.google.com/file/d/18QF-83jzDLfA9jSMn4KvvuTkKiY2nm9u/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your guidance. I tried with higher version GCC 7.0, enable internet on server and run "./contrib/download_prerequisites". It resolved issue and GCC installed sucessfully.