# "g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=gnu++14’" with gcc version 9.3.0

Tags: node.js, gcc, centos7

I have the `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)` running in the VirtualBox, which was build by the `Vagrant 2.2.19` and the `Ansible 2.9.25` installed all the depedencies. On the machine there are installed:

```
gcc 9.3.0
python 3.6.8
node.js 16.13.1
npm 8.1.2
```

When the ansible executes the `npm install` I get errored with the `g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=gnu++14’`. I saw many questions here on the Stackoverflow, where the answers told me to upgrade the gcc to version >= 4.9. But I already have that and I'm still getting an error.

However, there is a workaround, which allows me to run the `npm install`:

```sh
sudo yum install -y centos-release-scl
sudo yum install -y devtoolset-9-gcc*
scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
npm install
```

but I have to run this manually, after I'm logged into the CentOS by the `vagrant ssh`. I'm not satisfied with this workaround because it is manual and the `npm istall` must be run programatically, hence it doesn't solve my problem.

I have tried to execute the `npm install` inside the `scl` from the ansible `playbook.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Install centos-release-scl
  shell: yum install -y centos-release-scl
  become: yes

- name: Install devtoolset-9
  shell: yum install -y devtoolset-9-gcc*
  become: yes

- name: install packages based on package.json
  shell: |            
    scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
    npm install 
  become: yes
```

but it didn't work.

Is there a way how can I run the `npm install` programatically by the `ansible` without getting error?

Comment: The "devtoolset-9-gcc-c++" (g++) is using the gcc-4.8 version `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` , and C++14 features are not all included in gcc until version 5.0 https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html ...... Other extra gcc-c++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you for you answer, but as I said, the "devtoolset-9" is not an option for me, so I have upgraded the gcc by compiling it from source as its described in here: https://www.cyberithub.com/install-gcc-and-c-compiler/ but I have installed the version 11.2. The `gcc -v` and `g++ -v` both returned version 11.2 but the `cc -v` returned 4.8. I assume the nody-gyp is still using the 4.8 version, hence the error. I must find a way how to tell the node-gyp to use newer version.

Comment: The system compiler **gcc-4.8.5** : `/usr/bin/cc` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/gcc` . ... Solution: Delete or rename the link. Then create a new link cc -> gcc version 11.2 .

Answer (score 5):

For CentOS run this.

```bash
yum install gcc-c++
```

Then Install cmake.

```bash
yum install cmake
```

Then run.

```bash
yum install centos-release-scl
```

Install devtoolset.

```bash
yum install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++
```

Enable devtoolset.

```bash
scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash
```

Comment: It works for me with NodeJs 17 on CentOs 7

Comment: perfect! it works for me, trying to compile nodejs 19

Answer (score 3):

You can stick with gcc 4.8.5 but **downgrading to NodeJS 14** (as pointed out in https://github.com/systemd/node-sd-notify/issues/29#issuecomment-1040909033).

Note: You can download NodeJS 14 at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#enterprise-linux-based-distributions

Comment: Thanks! `nvm install 14` and `nvm use 14` worked..