# Compile old gcc version on Centos 8

Tags: c++, gcc, gdal

I'm struggling compiling an old GCC version on Centos 8.
Basic development tools come with GCC 8.5, but I would need to get GCC 5.3.
I've tried the following:

```
yum install glibc.i686 ncurses-libs.i686
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.3.0/gcc-5.3.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf gcc-5.3.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.3.0/
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc/5.3.0 --disable-multilib
make
sudo make install
```

But I always end-up with error at make stage. Also made a try with https://github.com/BobSteagall/gcc-builder, but no more success.
Final use case is to be able to compile GDAL on Centos 8 with MrSID driver, however MrSID is compiled with GCC 5.3, and I get errors at GDAL compilation with GCC 8.5

Comment: do you have source code for the MrSID driver?

Comment: i have the sdk from here https://www.extensis.com/support/developers

Comment: then why don't just rebuild the driver in newer GCC? If there are errors then fix it. That way it'll be easier going forward

Comment: Example build, gcc-5.3.0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n-Q_n6lIBUai2wyYooRVMq2OnC7VZuGG/view?usp=sharing .......... Extra gcc´ for CentOS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915