# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found on program generated locally that does not even have high version gcc

Tags: gcc, centos7

Since python3.10 onnx 1.8.0 does not exist on pypi, so I compiled it locally on Centos 7 machine. I've installed python2 pip and the necessary protoc compiler. I was able to generate a whl successfully, but the `.so` file generated can not find `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` and `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`

```
[root@a16802096fa7 onnx-1.8.0]# ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnx/onnx_cpp2py_export.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnx/onnx_cpp2py_export.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnx/onnx_cpp2py_export.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnx/onnx_cpp2py_export.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/onnx/onnx_cpp2py_export.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdb81f3000)
        libprotobuf.so.23 => /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so.23 (0x00007f89cf2f1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f89cf0d5000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f89cedcd000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f89ceacb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f89ce8b5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f89ce4e7000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f89ce2d1000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f89cfc33000)
```

This is abnormal since on this machine, it only contains gcc 4.8.5 which does not have those 2 GLIBCXX symbols, and I know this could be solved by upgrading gcc to 5.4.0, but how could this happen? Why would it need 2 symbols that does not even exist on this machine?

Comment: `GCC 5.1.0: GLIBCXX_3.4.21` : Something related to the app must have been compiled with g++ -5.x.x . Solution: Get `libstdc++.so.6.0.21` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNNTIzU2thRlZmYVE/view?usp=drive_link&resourcekey=0-clstEF4f2H0pCo8iSrwiMg , and point to it ....... or: gcc53-c++-5.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915 , which includes `libstdc++.so.6.0.21`